# changing row values into multi index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Considering this sample data:

```
          mem   Admits  AdmPerK
Month           
JAN        1       2    3
FEB        4       5    6
```

I am attempting, I think, to introduce a multi index and create this result:

```
          JAN                       FEB
<index>   mem   Admits  AdmPerK     mem Admits  AdmPerK    
                
    0     1      2       3          4     5      6
```

Tried the following;

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns) 
df.T
```

Neither worked nor did a couple of other transformation attempts.  Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: `df.stack().to_frame().T` would do the job, but has your real case more rows? do you always expect only 1 row in the output?

Comment: @Ben.T I will try this option now.  To your question, this is a test dataframe and once I get it transformed properly, in a loop I will be transforming 40 such dataframes and then concatenating them together.

Comment: @Ben.T  Okay, I will try that as well.  Looking into it now.

Comment: I just tried the @Ben.T code, it does work.

Comment: Yes.  @Ben.T's code work perfectly.  Thanks again.  I upvoted it as usual.

Comment: @Ben.T  One last little question, in the result I am getting using your suggestion, how would I rename the '0' that appears below the index column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the job by chaining `stack`, `to_frame` and `T` (for transpose). To give a specific name to the final index, use the parameter `name` in `to_frame`. With an example

```
#input data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': ['JAN', 'FEB'], 'mem': [1, 4], 
                   'Admits': [2, 5], 'AdmPerK': [3, 6]})
df = df.set_index('Month')
print(df)
#        mem  Admits  AdmPerK
# Month                      
# JAN      1       2        3
# FEB      4       5        6

#reshape
res = df.stack().to_frame(name='whatyouwant').T
print(res)
Month       JAN                FEB               
            mem Admits AdmPerK mem Admits AdmPerK
whatyouwant   1      2       3   4      5       6
```

Comment: I mean, shoot @Ben T that worked perfectly.  I have no idea how you figure these complex transformations out.  Nice!

Comment: @JohnTaylor mostly try to answer questions here, and when someoelse write an answer, then one learns new tricks :)

Comment: Absolutely.  Thanks again @Ben T.  So much appreciated.